# Is it possible to use one label element for multiple select elements in an HTML5 form?

Tags: html, forms, label

I am working on an assignment for an online web development course I am taking. The assignment is to create an HTML form.

One of the requirements is for there to be 3 dropdown menus - one for month, day, and year. A label of "Birthday:" is to precede these three menus.

The course's assignment solution showed three select elements nested inside of one label element. I tried this and, although it looked normal in the browser, when I uploaded the file to [W3C](https://validator.w3.org/) I received the following error:

"Error: The label element may contain at most one button, input, meter, output, progress, select, or textarea descendant."

Is there a proper way to use one label element to be applied to multiple select elements? Or is this a poor practice and instead each day, month, and year should each get its own label?

Here is my code:

```html
<div>
  <label>Birthday:
   <select name="month" required>
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
    <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
    <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
    <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
   </select>

   <select name="day" required>
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>

   <select name="year" required>
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="1918">1918</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
   </select>
  </label>
 </div>
```

  -

Comment: No, that is the standard I think. But, you need not wrap the drop-downs inside the label element anyway. You can just put label, and the drop-downs in divisions and format them as you need!

Comment: Group related form controls in a `<fieldset>`

Comment: @zer00ne - After reading a little about fieldset, I removed the label element and instead nested the select elements in a fieldset. It then validated in W3C. Thank you.

Comment: @Marc you are very welcome, sir. Be aware that while `<fieldset>` is rendered correctly in Chrome, Firefox may still be a little off.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, `<input />` fields are »primitive«, which means, each one represents a single value primitive value like a number, string, boolean, etc. A Birth date, consisting of three values, one for the year, the month and the day is »complex« in that context. So you cannot make HTML »understand« that you are trying to create a »complex« field in that way.

That's why (imho) you should not attach the label (complex) to any of the fields (primitive) and use the label as »decoration« without any connection to any field, than you wont get any validation errors.

`<label>`'s as wrapping elements can be helpful (especially for radio buttons) to expand the »clicking area/hitbox« and to apply some css, depending on the fields value, without any javascript. Otherwise linking labels to fields is cool for search engines and stuff, but since HTML does not have a standardized definition about: »how to label complex inputs«, it is difficult to say if the proposed approach is helpful, or will be in the future (afik).

So in your case, I would just:

```
<form>
  <div class="complex field-group">
    <label>…</label>
    <div class="fields">
      <!-- eventually to help bots 
        <label for="x" style="display:none;">…</label>
      -->
        <input id="x"/>

      …
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```